# Migration from jquery to react with vite

Tags: reactjs

I have a huge project using asp.net and jquery. I want to start migrating to react page by page (it might take a lot of time).
I would like to know what is the best practice to do it.

1. Can I move pages to react partially (for example half of page), and is it good approach?
2. Lets say I have main page A with with links to page B and C. Can I move page B and C to react, using routing, without moving page A right now?
3. I think I will use Vite to create and manager react project. In the production vite generates static files so I will simply host new files next to old ones in my backend server.
   The problem is with development, because in this mode vite creates new server with functions like hotreload and in the result I have two diffrent servers hosting frontend asp.net and vite.
   I would prefer to have just one server also for development. Is it possible to build development version with vite and copy it to server the same way like in production? Is this good approach?

I know that it would be the best to have backend and frontend server separated, but project is so huge that it is not possible in the foreseeable future